# What is the use of SKIPLINKTEXT property in Menu/wizard or any other controls

Tags: asp.net

Anyone please tell me what is the use of SkiplinkText property. I have seen example on the following link [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.skiplinktext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But after executing that sample, i am not able to understand what is the use of that property.

Answer (score 0):

Adding  `SkipLinkText=""` to `<asp:Menu>` to avoid the **rendering.**

> Ex:

The ASP.NET menu creates a skiplink which has 0x19 size and it is invisible in explorer, but it is rendered in chrome! So menu has an extra 19 pixels indent! How do I overcome this? Here is it's HTML:

```
<a href="#HeaderMenu1_Menu1_SkipLink">
<img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/WebResource.axd?d=ChOum_wTGSzbwK97BQPV0ITybaR8NYj0fCEsJDNZ46Dhv_eO5a-qipjyNL4I6aiynUitzcOuIwIjwyFX_snxVbyAZO7glY1Vhbd4zETG4j41&amp;t=634280594527374621" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;">
</a>
```

Add `SkipLinkText=""` to  tag and this code won't be rendered.

Comment: hi vignesh, what is the use of this image?

Comment: hi this is just example to make a image like..

hope this help you